# How to pre-calculate, in C++, a template type and use it in different modules

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have an compiler optimisation problem.

Let A, B, C three classes and static_update_manager another class yet implemented.

The static_update_manager have to be used as follow:

```
typedef typename static_update_manager<A>::type manager_t;
```

The definition of manager_t is placed inside a header file called manager.hpp and
that header is used by lots of modules.

During the compilation process, static_update_manager::type is calculated
and replaced by

```
static_update_manager_lst< boost::mpl::vector<A, B, C> >
```

The time to calculate the type of manager_t is very long and take lots of memory.
The problem is that all the modules are performing that calculus.
But, in fact, we need to do that work just one time.

Is there a C++ mechanism to do that ?

One idea could be to use gcc to convert the file manager.hpp to another file
manager_compiled.hpp looking like :

```
typedef typename static_update_manager_lst< boost::mpl::vector<A, B, C> > manager_t;
```

and to use manager_compiled.hpp in all the modules instead of manager.hpp.

But I don't know how to do that correctly.

I have an horrible solution :
 the idea is to make a script, compiling a source code with an error containing 
 the type of manager_t, and then, axtract the calculated type with grep in
 order to construct the header manager_compiled.hpp.

Comment: You could try a pre-compiled header.

Comment: Static type safety is great but sometimes the price is just too high. Perhaps you can shift some of this to run time and reduce complexity.

Comment: Thanks @NeilKirk , I have tried your idea by following that [web page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html).
But, unfortunately, the precompiled header `manager.hpp.gch` have a size of 1.2 Go, and the compilation time of my modules increases instead of decreasing.

Comment: Wow!!!!!!!!! That's a very complicated class. It will take longer to create the precompiled header, but the idea is subsequent compilations will be faster (so long as the header is not changed)